# Finding the volume using cylindrical shells??

Tags: calculus, volume

use cylindrical shells to compute the volume of the solid remaining when a hole of radius 1 is drilled through the center of a sphere of radius 5
I Know the bounds are from 1 to 5 but other than that I'm stuck on what to do please help

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use cylindrical shells in this case. There's a simple formula for it. [Napkin ring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napkin_ring_problem)